# Xml-Rpc.Net Server Method Missing Params with Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, server, xml-rpc.net

Is it possible with CookComputing's XmlRpc.Net to configure a server to ignore the missing `<params />` element when the server method has a `params object[] args` parameter?

I have a server method with something like the following signature:

```
[XmlRpcMethod("add_numbers")]
int AddAllTheNumbers(params object[] args);
```

And this works perfectly when testing with some clients. The problem is, there are a couple of clients who, when they have no parameters to send, don't output the empty `<params />` or `<params></params>` tag.

So the client is sending something like:

```
<methodCall>
    <methodName>add_numbers</methodName>
</methodCall>
```

With no `params` elements. Any ideas on how to allow this request through with CookComputing's XmlRpc.Net library?

Comment: Can you update with the exception being thrown?

Comment: The original error was "Method takes parameters and params element is missing."